# Kafka partition distribution in a (logically connected) group of topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

My use case is, at a high level, that of a standard change data capture (CDC) system - the consumers are listening to 2 topics, one for snapshot data and the other for incremental data.

During a historical data load, it is possible a consumer gets snapshot and incremental messages for the same entity. The consumers are idempotent, as a version info is stamped to every event.

However, to avoid race conditions anyway, is there a way to ensure the partitions for snapshot and incremental topic are distributed to same consumer? (so that for the same entity, be it snapshot event or incremental event, is processed by the same consumer thread).

Comment: It's possible... you need to write your own implementation of `AbstractPartitionAssignor` in such a way that consumers listen to the same partitions on both topics (assuming messages are partitioned on the same key and each topic has the same number of partitions). This might be a good use for Kafka streams (even though I avoid it like the plage) as it allows to join messages from multiple streams.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, messages will be partitioned on the same key and each topic will have the same number of partitions. Will explore AbstractPartitionAssignor. Also, I assumed streams will be able to leverage something, but then again, I too want to avoid streams.